# Pokemon Go is connected to your Gmail account, So is there a way to access it from a computer?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there some possible way to play or access your pokemon go account from a computer?

Answer (score 2):

No at the moment there is no way to access it from your computer.

Maybe they will develop an api with which developers can talk to make websites or apps which can track you or other people.

Answer (score 1):

Pokemon GO is solely a mobile app. Therefore, it is impossible to it to be used on a PC without the use of an emulator (a bannable offense).

In addition to the fact that the game is only designed for mobile, the majority of  computers have no GPS chips or any ability to connect from WiFi. Even if you had a mobile laptop, you still wouldn't be able to actually play the game without these things.

Now, if you're a game administrator or a Niantic employee, there is an admin control panel so that they can manipulate the game, but they still can't play it.